# Trouble detecting the number of blocks drawn on the board *XNA*

Tags: c#, xna

I have this code that draws the boxes on a Qbert board, how would i figure out how to detect what color blocks are stepped on?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace QBert
{
    public class Map
    {
        public int[,] board;
        public Color[] blockColors = new Color[] { Color.Blue, Color.Green }; //this makes it so it takes one time to step  to get to green
        Texture2D block;



        public Map(Texture2D block)   //draws the map of the blocks
        {
            this.block = block;

            board = new int[8, 7] 
            {
                { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
                { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
                { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
                { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 },

            }
            ;
        }

        public Vector2 GetSquareCoords(int x, int y) //cordinates of the block
        {
            int ofs = block.Width / 2;
            ofs *= y % 2;

            return new Vector2(x * block.Width + ofs, y * 96); // 96  
        }

        public Vector2 GetSquareCenter(int x, int y)  //method for to jump on the middle of a block
        {
            Vector2 coords = GetSquareCoords(x, y);

            return new Vector2(coords.X + block.Width / 2, coords.Y + 32); //32
        }


        public Vector2 GetNextSquare(bool down, bool left, Vector2 position)  //this is how you jump to a next square
        {
            // If on even row, right is directly below and left is below and to the left
            // If on odd row, left is directly below and right is below and to the right
            int next_x = 0, next_y = 0;
            int x = (int)position.X;
            int y = (int)position.Y;

            if (down)
            {
                next_y = y + 1;
                if (left)
                {
                    next_x = x - 1;  // -1
                }
                else
                {
                    next_x = x;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                next_y = y - 1;

            }

            if (y % 2 == 0)
            {

                if (left)
                    next_x = x - 1;
                else
                    next_x = x;


            }
            else
            {
                if (left)
                    next_x = x;
                else
                    next_x = x + 1;  //+1 

            }


            if (next_x < 0)
            {
                next_x += 1;

            }
            if (next_x > 6)
            {
                next_x -= 1;

            }
            if (next_y < 0)
            {
                next_y += 1;

            }
            if (next_y > 7)
            {
                next_y -= 1;

            }


            if (board[next_y, next_x] == 0)
            {
                return new Vector2(x, y);
            }
            else
            {
                return new Vector2(next_x, next_y);
            }


        }


        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) //draws the blocks and colors of the block
        {
            int drawXOffset = 30;
            int drawYOffset = 60;


            for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
                for (int y = 0; y < 7; y++)
                {
                    Vector2 coord = GetSquareCoords(x, y);
                    if (board[y, x] > 0)
                        spriteBatch.Draw(block, new Rectangle(drawXOffset + (int)coord.X, drawYOffset + (int)coord.Y, block.Width, block.Height), blockColors[board[y, x] - 1]);




                }
        }
    }
    }
```

I am trying to have the code detect the number of blocks drawn so that I know when they are all a certain color.

I need to make it a certain color of a block to end the game.

Right now, i have it starting out as a Blue Block Color then changing to a Green Block, how would i make it detect that if all the green blocks are stepped on that the game ends?

Comment: You probably will find it is much easier to store the board as a [triangular matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere in your `Update` method, you will want something like this:

```
bool finished = true;
for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 7; y++)
    {
        if (board != 0 && board != 2) // 2 is green
        {
            finished = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (finished)
        break;
}
if (finished)
{
    // Move to next level
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think somthing like this is what you want

```
public Vector2 GetNextSquare(bool down, bool left, Vector2 position)  
{
    int x = (int)position.X;
    int y = (int)position.Y;

//...other code

   if (blockColors[board[next_y, next_x]] == Color.Green)
   {
      //End
   }
   else if (board[next_y, next_x] == 0)
   {
        return new Vector2(x, y);
   }
   else
   {
        return new Vector2(next_x, next_y);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you have some sort of data representing your game field and rendering code simply renders visual representation of the field. Your game code only works with internal field representation (i.e. in your case set of cubes objects with "Color" property).

You definitely can check color on the screen, but it will require significantly more effort.

Comment: what do you mean, can you show me an example how i can check?

Comment: @ElliotWood shows reasonable sample `blockColors[board[next_y, next_x]]`. I personally would put objects instead of integers into board. I.e. object with CurrentColor, IsPresent properties, maybe even screen position. At least consider directly putting Color to the board with some special (i.e. Black/None) value for the cubes that are not present.

Answer (score 0):

**@Jaview "what do you mean, can you show me an example how i can check?"**

Here is an example how to get a pixel in XNA:

```
ResolveTexture2D backBufferData;

backBufferData = new ResolveTexture2D(
    graphics.GraphicsDevice,
    graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth,
    graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight,
    1,
    graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferFormat
);

Rectangle sourceRectangle = new Rectangle(Mouse.GetState().X, Mouse.GetState().Y, 1, 1);

Color[] retrievedColor = new Color[1];
graphics.GraphicsDevice.ResolveBackBuffer(backBufferData);

backBufferData.GetData<Color>(
    0,
    sourceRectangle,
    retrievedColor,
    0,
1);

selectedColor = retrievedColor[0];
```